# Can I prevent an `AsyncGenerator` from yielding after its `return()` method has been invoked?

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator

[AsyncGenerator.prototype.return() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncGenerator/return) states:

> The `return()` method of an async generator acts as if a `return` statement is inserted in the generator's body at the current suspended position, which finishes the generator and allows the generator to perform any cleanup tasks when combined with a [`try...finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_finally-block) block.

Why then does the following code print `0`–`3` rather than only `0`–`2`?

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const values = (async function* delayedIntegers() {
  let n = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield n++;
    await delay(100);
  }
})();

await Promise.all([
  (async () => {
    for await (const value of values) console.log(value);
  })(),
  (async () => {
    await delay(250);
    values.return();
  })(),
]);
```

I tried adding log statements to better understand where the "current suspended position" is and from what I can tell when I call the `return()` method the `AsyncGenerator` instance isn't suspended (the body execution isn't at a `yield` statement) and instead of returning once reaching the `yield` statement the next value is `yielded` and then suspended at which point the "return" finally happens.

Is there any way to detect that the `return()` method has been invoked and not `yield` afterwards?

---

I can implement the `AsyncIterator` interface myself but then I lose the `yield` syntax supported by async generators:

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const values = (() => {
  let n = 0;
  let done = false;
  return {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
      return this;
    },
    async next() {
      if (done) return { done, value: undefined };
      if (n !== 0) {
        await delay(100);
        if (done) return { done, value: undefined };
      }
      return { done, value: n++ };
    },
    async return() {
      done = true;
      return { done, value: undefined };
    },
  };
})();

await Promise.all([
  (async () => {
    for await (const value of values) console.log(value);
  })(),
  (async () => {
    await delay(250);
    values.return();
  })(),
]);
```

Comment: Try `yield ++n` instead of `yield n++`

Comment: That will only change the values returned from `0`–`3` to `1`–`4` but I will still get a total of 4 yielded values rather than the desired 3.

Comment: We discussed this a bunch when async generators were being added, see https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/126 for example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why does the code print `0–3` rather than only `0–2`? From what I can tell, when I call the `return()` method, the `AsyncGenerator` instance isn't suspended (the body execution isn't at a `yield` statement) and instead of returning once reaching the `yield` statement the next value is `yield`ed and then suspended at which point the "return" finally happens.

Yes, precisely this is what happens. The generator is already running because the `for await … of` loop did call its `.next()` method, and so the generator will complete that before considering the `.return()` call.

All the methods that you invoke on an async generator are **queued**. (In a sync generator, you'd get a "*TypeError: Generator is already running*" instead). One can demonstrate this by immediately calling `next` multiple times:

```js
const values = (async function*() {
  let i=0; while (true) {
    await new Promise(r => { setTimeout(r, 1000); });
    yield i++;
  }
})();
values.next().then(console.log, console.error);
values.next().then(console.log, console.error);
values.next().then(console.log, console.error);
values.return('done').then(console.log, console.error);
values.next().then(console.log, console.error);
```

> Is there any way to detect that the `return()` method has been invoked and not `yield` afterwards?

No, not from within the generator. And really you probably still *should* yield the value if you already expended the effort to produce it.

It sounds like what you want to do is to ignore the produced value when you want the generator to stop. You should do that in your `for await … of` loop - and you can also use it to stop the generator by using a `break` statement:

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});

async function* delayedIntegers() {
  let n = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield n++;
    await delay(1000);
  }
}

(async function main() {
  const start = Date.now();
  const values = delayedIntegers();
  for await (const value of values) {
    if (Date.now() - start > 2500) {
      console.log('done:', value);
      break;
    }
    console.log(value);
  }
})();
```

But if you really want to abort the generator from the outside, you need an out-of-band channel to signal the cancellation. You can use an [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) for this:

```js
const delay = (ms, signal) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  function done() {
    resolve();
    signal?.removeEventListener("abort", stop);
  }
  function stop() {
    reject(this.reason);
    clearTimeout(handle);
  }
  signal?.throwIfAborted();
  const handle = setTimeout(done, ms);
  signal?.addEventListener("abort", stop, {once: true});
});

async function* delayedIntegers(signal) {
  let n = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield n++;
    await delay(1000, signal);
  }
}

(async function main() {
  try {
    const values = delayedIntegers(AbortSignal.timeout(2500));
    for await (const value of values) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch(e) {
    if (e.name != "TimeoutError") throw e;
    console.log("done");
  }
})();
```

This will actually permit to stop the generator *during* the timeout, not after the full second has elapsed.

Comment: I like this, that's a good point in a lot of ways. "And really you probably still _should_ yield the value if you already expended the effort to produce it."

Comment: I think the `AbortSignal` solution is actually really good here. I had not thought of that before. It will work with `fetch` as well (if I weren't just sleeping but actually doing some IO). Thanks!

Comment: You can actually pass an AbortSignal directly to addEventListener which would save you the `removeEventListener` and wrapping the function.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What I need is to remove the listener when the promise is fulfilled, not when the `signal` is aborted. There's unfortunately no method to do that. (I'd love to see `new PromiseV2(resolve => { const handle = setTimeout(resolve, ms); return () => clearTimeout(handle); }, signal)`)

Comment: Writing this code by manually wiring the signals is very tricky, for example the code above leaks the event listener if the signal is aborted (removeEventListener is never called in stop). That's why it's usually easier to use the third argument of addEventListener `{ signal, once: true }` which takes care of this.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Since an `AbortSignal` cannot be aborted twice, I would dearly hope it does forget about the listener after firing. If it really is a dumb old DOM `EventTarget`, I consider the implementation broken - we really need to move forward with the ECMAScript cancellation protocol proposal.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Not sure how you suggest to use a signal here. You mean `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  signal?.throwIfAborted();  const ctrl = new AbortController();  const handle = setTimeout(() => { resolve(); ctrl.abort(); }, ms);  signal?.addEventListener("abort", () => { reject(signal.reason); clearTimeout(handle); }, { once: true, signal: ctrl.signal });  });`? Or did you mean `signal.addEventListener("abort", done, { signal })`? That seems like it would do exactly the same as `once: true`. Or even never call `done`, since the signal is already aborted when the event would fire.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to prevent this "extra yield" after invoking the return method? If not, are there libraries, patterns, etc. our there that avoid this while still implementing these AsyncIterator interface optional properties?

As @Bergi clearly explained, the extra yield cannot be avoided with the `AsyncGenerator.return()` method. This is a really interesting case, but I don't think you will find libraries that fix it. @Bergi proposed a clever solution using the `AbortSignal`, I have tried a different approach with only `Promise`s:

```js
(async function test() {
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const wrapIntoStoppable = function (generator) {
    const newGenerator = {
        isGeneratorStopped: false,
        resolveStopPromise: null,
        async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
            let stoppedSymbol = Symbol('stoppedPromise')
            let stoppingPromise

            while (true) {
                if (this.isGeneratorStopped)
                    return
                stoppingPromise = new Promise((resolve, _) => this.resolveStopPromise = resolve)
                    .then(_ => stoppedSymbol)
                nextValuePromise = generator.next()
                const result = await Promise.race([nextValuePromise, stoppingPromise])
                this.resolveStopPromise() // resolve the promise in case it is still pending
                if (result === stoppedSymbol)
                    return
                else
                    yield result.value
            }
        },    
        stop: function() {
            this.resolveStopPromise()
            this.isGeneratorStopped = true
        }
    }

    const handler = {
        get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
            if (['next', 'return', 'throw'].includes(prop))
                return generator[prop].bind(generator)
            else
                return newGenerator[prop].bind(newGenerator)
        }
    }
  
    return new Proxy(newGenerator, handler)
}

const values = wrapIntoStoppable((async function* delayedIntegers() {
    let n = 0;
    while (true) {
        yield n++;
        await delay(100);
    }
})());

await Promise.all([
    (async () => {
        for await (const value of values) {
            console.log(Date.now())
            console.log(value);
        }
        console.log(Date.now())
        // console.log(await values.next())
        // console.log(await values.return())
        // console.log(await values.throw())
    })(),
    (async () => {
        await delay(250);
        values.stop()
    })(),
]);
})();
```

The idea is that I wrap an async generator with an object that has an async iterator. All the elements yielded by the wrapping generator are yielded by the original generator, but now 2 promises are started:

- `nextValuePromise` that will return the value to yield
- `stoppingPromise` that will end the iteration if resolved before the previous one

In this way, if the `stop()` method (which resolves `stoppingPromise`) is called before the first promise is resolved, then `Promise.race()` will immediately return a dummy `Symbol`. When the result of the `race` is this symbol, the iterator returns. The `stop()` function also sets the `isGeneratorStopped` flag that makes sure the iterator will eventually return if the `stop()` method is called after the `stoppingPromise()` is manually resolved.

I have also used a `Proxy` to make sure that the wrapping object behaves as a  true `AsyncGenerator`. Calls to `next()`, `return()` or `throw()` are simply forwarded to the wrapped generator.

---

Let's see the pros:

1. `wrapIntoStoppable` can become a util method that just wraps any async generator. This is certainly convenient because you don't have to use signals every time there is a pending `Promise` <sup>1</sup>
2. Once the `stop()` method is called on the async generator, the `for await...of` loop immediately returns. Note: this doesn't mean that pending `Promise`s are aborted

And now the cons:

1. Maybe too much code to maintain? Now the generator has a proxy that wraps another wrapper... I would like to simplify the design at least
2. After the generator is `stop`ped, the `nextValuePromise()` could be resolved in the meantime, causing some potential side effects. This is the main reason why it is a pretty dangerous library function.

---

1. <sub>Actually, I think you could even merge @Bergi's and my solution and manage to abort a `Promise` when the `stop()` method is called. However, in this case, all the promises need to handle the abort signals.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`await` would suspend the `async` part of the function, but not the `generator` part, thus `AsyncGenerator.return()` can not act on the `await` suspension, but only `yield` suspension. And I think that's why `AsyncGenerator.return()` returns a promise, but `Generator.return()` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Bergi is right. The `for await` loop invokes `.next()` right after the consumption and puts `yield` in charge before `return`. So what happens is;

```
@  0ms 0 gets yielded and .next() puts yield in charge to yield 1 once resolved.
@100ms 1 gets yielded and .next() puts yield in charge to yield 2 once resolved.
@200ms 2 gets yielded and .next() puts yield in charge to yield 3 once resolved.
@250ms a values.return() is enqueued but yield has already been queued to yield 3.
@300ms 3 gets yielded and generator finalizes along with the iterable values.
```

Now the thing is, if we find a way to resolve or reject the promise waiting for 3 prematurely @250ms then we are fine. Yet without using the `abort` abstraction you can still do this with naked promises and even without using an async generator. You just need to lift the `resolve` and `reject` functions out of the generator functions scope and invoke from there. I think it's best to `reject` prematurely and `catch` the rejection at the outer scope (silent or not).

Here is a way to accomplish this;

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms)),
      prior = {};

const values = (function* delayedIntegers() {
  let n = 0,
      p = new Promise((v,x) => Object.assign(prior,{v,x}));
  prior.v(n++); // resolve p with 0 and increment n
  while (true) {
    yield p
    p = new Promise((v,x) => Object.assign(prior,{v,x}));
    delay(100).then(_ => prior.v(n++));
  }
})();

(async () => {
  try {
    for await (const value of values) console.log(value);
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    values.return();
  }
})();

delay(250).then(_ => prior.x("Finalized..!"));
```

This is almost like your code but there is this `prior` object which holds the `resolve` and `reject` functions of a promise callback as `v` and `x` respectively.

Since `prior` object is accessible from within the outer context we can invoke it's `x` method (rejection) before the while loop in the generator resolves 3 and catch the rejection with the employed `catch(e)`.